# How to add an admin restriction feature through Devise to my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

My rails app has a few cab operators and they have a few cabs, and they are related as follows:

```
class Operator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cabs
end
```

I wish to add authentication system so as to create admins for each operator. I am using Devise. Since I need to create path as: operator/:operator_id/admins/sign_up, I generated the Admin model, as:

```
rails generate devise Admin
```

Then I modified my routes so as to obtain the above mentioned path:

```
scope "operators/:operator_id" do 
    devise_for :admins
end
```

After a few more modifications, I was able to add new admins and associate them to appropriate operators. However, I want to ensure that an admin only has access to the cabs of the operator to which the admin is associated. Adding the following to the cabs_controller doesn't work:

```
before_action :authenticate_admin!
```

as a signed_in admin has access to all other operator's cabs. I want to make sure that:

```
1. If there is no current_admin, my app asks to sign_in or sign_up
2. If there already is a current__admin signed_in, he/she has access to only the cabs associated to that operator to which the current_admin is assigned.
```

I am new to Devise. Please advise how I should proceed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise is for Authentication, your problem is an Authorization problem which Devise cannot help. You can look into Cancan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to scope your devise for admins. I'm not sure if it would solve any issue with access. It also makes your code harder to maintain.

I would advise you to focus on relationships instead

```
class Operator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cabs
    has_many :admins
end


class Operator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cabs, through: operator
    belongs_to :operator
end
```

Normally the way I handle such cases later is to write special in the cab model :

```
  def is_admin?(admin)
      admin.cabs.include?(@cab)
      # you can put more logic here if you have different levels of access
  end
```

and later in the controller when you want to restrict access:

```
  if @cab.is_admin?(current_admin) 
     # do the stuff
  else
     # go away message
  end
```

or for instance if you list cabs in index:

```
  def index 
     current_admin.cabs.page(params[:page]) # this is assuming you're using pagination with something like Kaminari
  end
```

current_admin from divise, you may want to also run :authenticate_admin! before filter to make sure you have you admin and it's not nil

Of course you can put it in price message and run it as before filter.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to use STI and have Admin < User, then a couple of

```
devise_for :users
devise_for :admins
```

If you do not want to use STI, some custom overridings may do the trick, if you add a role method to your users table for exemple.

```
#routes
devise_for :users
namespace :admin do
  devise_for :admins,
           singular: :admin,
           plural: :admins,
           class_name: 'User',
           only: [:sessions],
           path: '/',
           module: :devise
end 


#lib/overrides/devise
require "devise/strategies/authenticatable"
require "devise/strategies/database_authenticatable"

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class DatabaseAuthenticatable
      def authentication_hash
        if mapping.name == :admin
          @authentication_hash.update(role: :admin) #will add a where(role: :admin) clause
        else
          @authentication_hash
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use role base Authentication.

Generate User model

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
     enum role: [:operator, :admin]
     after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

     def set_default_role
       self.role ||= :operator
     end

     # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
   end
```

generate migration to add role

```
rails g AddRoleToUser role:integer
```

Please take a look [ENUM](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)